# How can I get my friends events with the Graph API and PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking to get my friends events with the Graph API and PHP.

I'm getting my events with:

```
 $facebook->api('/me/events');
```

Is there a similar way?

Also, does anyone know of a reference for this?

Answer (score 4):

You need the `friends_events` permission in order to get the events of your friends also.

Once your application got this permission then you can the query the same as you did for your events with the graph API...

If your friend's Facebook id is `2343423434` then the API call would be:

```
$facebook->api('/2343423434/events');
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay, I do have the friends_events permission set, do you know of any way other than looping through their friends list to get friends events?

Comment: You can extend search by chaining request like this `me?fields=friends.fields(events)`. You can see more details [on facebook examples page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion)

Comment: This permission is not available anymore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640306/what-is-the-replacement-for-friends-events-permission-in-fb-graph-api-v2-0