# What is the replacement for friends_events permission in FB Graph API v2.0?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-permissions

I'm not interested in having list of friends, only events friends of my apps user have some connection with (preferably in manner of [`/user/events`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/events))

What is the correct replacement of `friends_events` permission in Graph API v2.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no replacement for this. All the `friends_*` permissions have been removed for the privacy reasons.

Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Oh, I've seen this changelog, but I don't see anything about it being removed for privacy, nor that they won't replace the functionality. Thank you though

Comment: Btw. is current call `{friend_id}/events` equivalent to previous function of API1.0 ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The API `{friend_id}/events` doenot exists now!

Comment: Sahil: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/events where `user-id` is ID of Friend

Comment: Sorry but I'm not able to understand your problem here! The `/friend-id/events` cannot be used now. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I've confused `user_friends` permission, which showed my friends already using the app with previous `friends_*` permissions, sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no replacement - there's no way to access data from friends of your app's users - this is mentioned here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Comment: Btw. is current call `{friend_id}/events` equivalent to previous function of API1.0 ?

Comment: If /v2.0/<friend id>/events returns data, that's most likely a bug - if so you should file it in the bug tracker

Comment: It does, but probably only public events, or events created by the user, it does return something for few of my friends.