# Facebook Graph API - Get friends attending an event?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm able to get a list of all attendees using the Facebook SDK,

```
FB.api("/{event-id}/attending",
  function (response) {
    if (response && !response.error) {
      /* handle the result */
    }
  }
);
```

I need to retrieve my friends who are attending an event using graph API.
There is a way to achieve this with FQL but I don't know how to implement it.

I need the solution using Java Script.

Comment: That is not directly possible via API. (And FQL is gone for _years_ now.)

Answer (score 1):

You can now no longer request event attendees without one of the event admins' access keys [(see Graph api reference)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/attending/). As facebook also [removed the option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640306/what-is-the-replacement-for-friends-events-permission-in-fb-graph-api-v2-0) to access friends' events for privacy reasons, there is currently no way of doing this solely via the Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need first to get list of all users attending to the event and filter it - so that only user's friends should be left in this list

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/event-id/?fields=attending
```